# Custom Wizard: Is it possible to add a dll reference to a project on creation from a custom wizard?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, assemblies, reference, wizard

I was wondering if anyone could tell me if what I'm trying to accomplish is possible.

I am using C# in VS 2008.

I have two project templates and another template which links the two projects and calls their templates.  The first project is a user control and the second is a test app that needs to reference the user control.  I also have  a custom wizard that is called from the template.  After the projects are created the wizard compiles the user control and gets the path to its dll. I then need to add a reference to the user control from the dll path to my test app.  It is not possible for me to add the reference before this as I don't know what the name of the dll will be until the user creates the new user control project giving it whatever name they want.  Does anyone know how this could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a DLL reference - could you use a project reference?